# Yield multiple empty dataframes by a function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, function, return, yield

I would like to yield multiple empty dataframes by a function in Python.

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = []

def create_multiple_df(num):

  for i in range(num):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df_name = "df_" + str(num)
    exec(df_name + " = df ")
    df_list.append(eval(df_name))
    
  for i in df_list:
    yield i
```

e.g. when I `create_multiple_df(3)`, I would like to have `df_1`, `df_2` and `df_3` returned.

However, it didn't work.

I have two questions,

1. How to store multiple dataframes in a list (i.e. without evaluating the contents of the dataframes)?
2. How to yield multiple variable elements from a list?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean how to create a dictionary? `dfs = {'df1': pd.DataFrame(), 'df2': pd.DataFrame(), ...}`

Answer (score 1):

It's *very* likely that you do not want to have `df_1`, `df_2`, `df_3` ... etc. This is often a design pursued by beginners for some reason, but trust me that a dictionary or simply a list will do the trick without the need to hold different variables.

Here, it sounds like you simply want a list comprehension:

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame() for _ in range(n)]
```

This will create `n` empty dataframes and store them in a list. To retrieve or modify them, you can simply access their position. This means instead of having a dataframe saved in a variable `df_1`, you can have that in the list `dfs` and use `dfs[1]` to get/edit it.

Another option is a dictionary comprehension:

```
dfs = {i: pd.DataFrame() for i in range(n)}
```

It works in a similar fashion, you can access it by `dfs[0]` or `dfs[1]` (or even have real names, e.g. `{f'{genre}': pd.DataFrame() for genre in ['romance', 'action', 'thriller']}`. Here, you could do `dfs['romance']` or `dfs['thriller']` to retrieve the corresponding df).